# Accessing specific USB ports for VB.net

Tags: vb.net, usb, wmi

New to VB.NET here. 
I was wondering if there is a way to determine if there is something connected to a specific USB port. For example, I noticed that in the Device Manager under Universal Serial Bus controllers, there are Generic USB Hubs. For one of them, the Location is Port_#0001.Hub_#0003.

For what I am doing, I just want to know if something is connected to that specific USB port. It doesn't matter if it is a flash drive, USB HID, or even a microcontroller.

Thanks

Comment: Another example is that when I plug my flash drive in, the Location is Port_#0004.Hub_#0004. I just want to know if there is something in that location or not.